# Google Visualization graphs loading on Firefox, never loading on Chrome, and occassionally loading on iPhone Safari

Tags: jquery, safari, google-visualization

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});

window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    //json structure has keys workout, completed, date, workout 1, workout 2, etc with associated value
    $.ajax({
        "url": "/json/testusername",
        "type": "GET",
        "datatype": 'json',
        "success": function(data){
                var wo = Object.keys(data[0]); // wo is the name of the workout. for some reason everything in whatever.json is data[0]
                var len = data.length; // this and the shifts below get rid of the metadata in the json and find the key name of each workout
                wo.shift(); // shift tosses the first object in the array, this tosses the "workout" key
                wo.shift(); // this tosses the "completed" key
                wo.shift(); // this tosses the "date" key
                for(var i=0; i<wo.length;i++){ // this creates 1 graph for each workout, but this loop strangely only runs once
                    $("#accordion").append("<h3>" + wo[i].replace(/_/g, " ") + "</h3>");
                    var accordionContent = document.createElement('div');
                    $(accordionContent).attr('id', wo[i]);
                    var table = [["date", wo[i]]]; // this creates an array with the keys "date" and "name of workout"
                    for(var q=0;q<data.length;q++){ // loops through the number of data entries
                        table.push([data[q]["date"], data[q][wo[i]]]); // adds a [date, numberOfReps] pairing to the array
                        }


                    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function(){ // google charts shenanigans
                        var d = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(table);
                        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(accordionContent);
                        var options = {
                              title: $(accordionContent).attr('id').replace(/_/g, " "),
                              width: $("#accordion").width(),
                              curveType: 'function',
                              legend: { position: 'none' }

                            };
                        chart.draw(d, options);
                        $("#accordion").append(accordionContent);
                    });
                }
                 $(function() {
                  $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
                      collapsible: true
                        });
                  });

            }
        });

});
```

This displays as [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRJVl.png) on Firefox, which is exactly what I want. On iPhone Safari (haven't tried with any other mobile device, about 90% of the time and desktop Chrome 100%, it will appear like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTg9z.png). The other 10% of the time, it seems to work fine. I see no errors running this on any browser. I think it's probably an issue with trying to append a chart to a div that hasn't been appended yet. What's going on, and where did I go wrong? Seems like async shenanigans to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, probably don't need both
`google.charts.setOnLoadCallback`
and
`window.addEventListener('load'...`

next, be sure to...
`$("#accordion").append(accordionContent);`

before...
`chart.draw(d, options);`

try something like this...

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    //json structure has keys workout, completed, date, workout 1, workout 2, etc with associated value
    $.ajax({
        "url": "/json/testusername",
        "type": "GET",
        "datatype": 'json',
        "success": function(data){
                var wo = Object.keys(data[0]); // wo is the name of the workout. for some reason everything in whatever.json is data[0]
                /*not used*/ var len = data.length; // this and the shifts below get rid of the metadata in the json and find the key name of each workout
                wo.shift(); // shift tosses the first object in the array, this tosses the "workout" key
                wo.shift(); // this tosses the "completed" key
                wo.shift(); // this tosses the "date" key
                for(var i=0; i<wo.length;i++){ // this creates 1 graph for each workout, but this loop strangely only runs once
                    $("#accordion").append("<h3>" + wo[i].replace(/_/g, " ") + "</h3>");
                    var accordionContent = document.createElement('div');
                    $("#accordion").append(accordionContent);
                    $(accordionContent).attr('id', wo[i]);
                    var table = [["date", wo[i]]]; // this creates an array with the keys "date" and "name of workout"
                    for(var q=0;q<data.length;q++){ // loops through the number of data entries
                        table.push([data[q]["date"], data[q][wo[i]]]); // adds a [date, numberOfReps] pairing to the array
                    }

                    var d = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(table);
                    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(accordionContent);
                    var options = {
                          title: $(accordionContent).attr('id').replace(/_/g, " "),
                          width: $("#accordion").width(),
                          curveType: 'function',
                          legend: { position: 'none' }

                        };
                    chart.draw(d, options);
                }
                 $(function() {
                  $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
                      collapsible: true
                        });
                  });

            }
        });
  },
  packages:['corechart']
});
```